# Jenkins: Gerrit & Git plugin - missing refspec field?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gerrit, automated-tests

I am trying to set up a Jenkins job (actually it's a MultiJob, but I don't think this is relevant at this point), with a Gerrit trigger.

The documentation for the [Gerrit Trigger with the Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger#GerritTrigger-UsagewiththeGitPlugin) gives instructions for the correct refspecs, choosing strategy and branch. However, in my job setup, I do not have settings for the refspec and choosing strategy, and the options are not the same as [those shown](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/45481993/git_config.png?version=1&modificationDate=1278331124000) in the Gerrit trigger docs.

This is what I have:
[image: Available Git settings]

Do I have the wrong version of a plugin, or are the documentation instructions out-of-date? Or am I looking in the wrong place for the Git settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is hidden in the `Advanced` section.

Comment: And the other settings below are now all found in a drop down rather than listed individually.

Comment: Can't tell you how thankful I am that you wrote this!