# Errors in Jenkins when trying to propagate to Gerrit server

Tags: jenkins, gerrit

I'm trying to get a CI process set up, using gerrit and jenkins.  I've successfully configured jenkins to trigger a build on gerrit events, and everything's working ok on that front, I can see the build succeeding in the jenkins log.  The problem I'm having is in trying to send the build results back to gerrit.   I've set up a "Post-build Action" for gerrit integration, and all the fields look correct, but when I do the build I get this stack trace:

```
ERROR: Publisher hudson.plugins.gerrit.GerritNotifier aborted due to exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find GIT_HOME in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/jake/workspace/.git
at hudson.plugins.gerrit.git.GitTools.getHead(GitTools.java:45)
at hudson.plugins.gerrit.GerritNotifier$1.invoke(GerritNotifier.java:180)
at hudson.plugins.gerrit.GerritNotifier$1.invoke(GerritNotifier.java:171)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:914)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:887)
at hudson.plugins.gerrit.GerritNotifier.perform(GerritNotifier.java:171)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:714)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:182)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:663)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1714)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:231)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I've put in commands in the build process to examine the filesystem, and yeah I definitely don't have a .git directory there.   (I do have a /var/.../workspace/.repo/repo/.git, but symlinking that to /var/.../workspace/.git  didn't work, although it gave a different error that I wish I had saved, I can re-run that if it'd be helpful)

So my question is: how should I configure the jenkins job to properly connect to the gerrit server?

(I don't have easy access to the gerrit server, but I'm operating on the assumption that things are set up there because (a) jenkins is getting the data from it properly and (b) the error doesn't look at all like a connection error)

EDIT: The optimal thing would be for jenkins to set +1/-1 in the Verified options, depending on the result of the build, but even if it could leave a comment on the review page with a link to each run, that would be at least something...

EDIT 2:  On HiB's suggestion, I switched over to the git plugin, and got this stack trace:

```
FATAL: org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository
java.lang.InstantiationError: org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository
at hudson.plugins.gerrit.git.GitTools.getRepository(GitTools.java:24)
at hudson.plugins.gerrit.git.GitTools.getHead(GitTools.java:48)
at hudson.plugins.gerrit.GerritNotifier$1.invoke(GerritNotifier.java:180)
at hudson.plugins.gerrit.GerritNotifier$1.invoke(GerritNotifier.java:171)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:914)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:887)
at hudson.plugins.gerrit.GerritNotifier.perform(GerritNotifier.java:171)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:714)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:182)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:663)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1714)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:231)
```

(there wasn't even a "Finished: FAILURE" warning)

Removing the post-build action results in "Finished: SUCCESS" but nothing's showing up in gerrit.

Comment: can you please give screenshot about gerrit trigger Adavanced settings? By the way git plugin is not needed if you dont use it.

Comment: also please add the output of the job which should begin with: "Triggered by Gerrit" followed by the link of the change. By the way -  are you using [this plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger)?

Comment: Here's the job output: https://gist.github.com/kesinger/16e7b3a9c3c243df79a9

Comment: And here's the screenshot, this is from the job configuration page so it's the defaults: http://imgur.com/KB1ecL1

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found [this](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgroups.google.com%2Fd%2Fmsg%2Fjenkinsci-users%2Fm-_YthtTXvI%2FKpags7VejZwJ&ei=s0wEVM_rOI6v7Aa7tIDQCA&usg=AFQjCNHQ3yZ1p9CzWeVFzNicAs-HWLzUBw&bvm=bv.74115972,d.ZGU) solution:
deactivating the "Hudson Gerrit plugin" V0.7

It worked for me.
Apparently I don't need this plugin - no features have disappeared after deactivating it (as far as I saw 'till now...).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you set the Gerrit plugin using [these instructions](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger). So double check the *Git Plugin* settings and the `Advanced...` section at *Gerrit Trigger* settings which is missing from the guide. if *URL to post* param is empty, then the result message will contain the build result URL - and you can set a custom message for each result at *Custom build message*. The verify value can be set at *Verify* subsection.
you don't need to bother with git repo at all, if all the git plugin settings configured properly. This related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22453442/1342413) perhaps is useful as well.
And no need to define any *Post-build Action* if everything is ok. Unless you want to setup an UNSTABLE state...

Comment: I was not using the git plugin, as we need multiple repositories to do the full build.  
I modified the build targets and gave it a try tho, and got a different exception which I'll edit into my original message.  Taking out the post-build action, I get a "Finished: SUCCESS" notification but nothing shows up in gerrit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gerrit Trigger and nothing shows up in Gerrit even if everything is correctly set, you might want to look at the Gerrit server settings (Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Gerrit Trigger -> Your server name under 'Gerrit Servers').

Depending on your Gerrit version, the default values in Gerrit Verified Commands that you will find if you click on the 'Advanced' button might be wrongly set. I have Gerrit 2.8 and had to change the `--label <VERIFIED>` parameter in `--label Verified=<VERIFIED>`
More generally, if the log reports that Jenkins has given feedback to Gerrit but nothing shows up in the Gerrit interface, it might be because the default values in those input fields are wrongly set.